# ant build.xml file doesn't exist

Tags: java, ant

After the installation of my ant in my windows 7 . In cmd i typed **ant -v** it's given the ant version but it says the following also.

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

What's the problem in the system. How i can rectify this issue?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You should use `ant -version` command instead. 
The `-v` option is equivalent of `-verbose` option. 
See [Command-line Options Summary](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)

Answer (score 14):

If I understand correctly, you assumed that `-v` is the "print version" command. Check the documentation, that is not the case -- instead `ant -v` is running ant build in `verbose` mode. So ant is trying to perform your build, based on the `build.xml` file, which is obviously not there.

To answer your question explicitly: there is probably nothing wrong with both the system nor ant installation.

Answer (score 6):

may be you can specify where the buildfile is located and then invoke desired action.

Eg:    ant -file {BuildfileLocation/build.xml} -v

Answer (score 5):

You have invoked Ant with the verbose (-v) mode but the default buildfile `build.xml` does not exist.  Nor have you specified any other `buildfile` for it to use.

I would say your Ant installation is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you couldn't find the build.xml file in your project then you have to build it to be able to debug it and get your **.apk**

you can use this **command-line** to build:

```
android update project -p "project full path"
```

where "Project full path" -- Give your full path of your project location

after this you will find the build.xml then you can debug it.

Answer (score 1):

this one works in ubuntu
This command will cre
android update project -p "project full path"

Answer (score 0):

There may be two situations.

1. No build.xml is present in the current directory
2. Your ant configuration file has diffrent name.

Please see and confim the same.
In the case one you have to find where your build file is located and in the case 2, You will have to run command `ant -f <your build file name>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have still this issue i have my build.xml file inside the sample folder .
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Please install at ubuntu openjdk-7-jdk

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

on Windows try find find openjdk

Answer (score -3):

Using ant debug after building build.xml file :

in your cmd your root should be your project at first then use the ant debug command
e.g:

```
c:\testApp>ant debug
```