# Ant gaves me an error Build xml doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, ant

I'm trying to debug a Java Android app but when I type `ant debug` on the command line I get:

```
Buildfile: Build.xml doesn't exist
```

I'm using Ant 1.9 but it does not include `Build.xml`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information like what computer language you are using and maybe a look at your code?

Comment: ... Does your project have a `build.xml` file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ant build.xml file doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528517/ant-build-xml-file-doesnt-exist)

Comment: No my project hasn t The Build.xml file ..  Mark that doesn't help me The question si another one

Comment: @user3621396 If your project doesn't have a `build.xml` file then why are you trying to use Ant to do *anything*? You might want to read some Ant docs before going much further.

Comment: @DaveNewton I ve added the build.xml file on my Project but nothing to do..

Comment: You're not providing any information anybody could use to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the directory containing the project, run the "android update project" command to create the build.xml file (plus some others). For example:

```
E:\Develop\AccelerometerPlay> android update project --path . --target android-19
```

Make sure that the target platform in installed in the SDK manager.